# Does removing the "free space" partition and resizing my main partition in Disk Utility delete my data?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, storage

I deleted my Windows partition a few days ago and was left with a space called "free space" in the partition pie chart within disk utility. I'm planning to reinstall Windows but it seems like I can't without first removing that free space partition and adding it to my macOS partition. I have a 2TB fusion drive.

[image: This is what the chart looks like.]

Is it possible to remove this free space partition without losing all of the data on my main drive? For the life of me I can't figure out if it's as simple as clicking the minus button and removing it but I really don't want to do anything I'm not sure about.

EDIT: Here's the output from `diskutil list`:

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         121.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         833.0 GB   disk1s2
                    (free space)                         1.2 TB     -

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +954.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     822.7 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 337.6 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                622.9 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      2.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            22.2 GB    disk2s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 22.2 GB    disk2s5s1
```

And here's the output from `sw_vers`:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.6
BuildVersion:   20G165
```

Ran `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0` in recovery mode, got an error.

```
Started APFS operation
Aligning grow delta to 1,167,206,715,392 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 2,000,189,177,856 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 2,000,188,149,760 bytes
Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk4
The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk1s2
Verifying storage system
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x /dev/disk0s2
Checking the container superblock
Checking the fusion superblock
Checking the EFI jumpstart record
Checking the space manager
Checking the space manager free queue trees
Checking the object map
Checking the Fusion data structures
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking snapshot 1 of 2 (com.apple.os.update-5DC2B8AA591ED241EC5D606CA1EC8CA686322F70563020EFC688A81456FCA796)
Checking snapshot 2 of 2 (com.apple.os.update-MSUPrepareUpdate)
warning: snapshot fsroot/file key rolling tree corruptions are not repaired; they'll go away once the snapshot is deleted
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking the file extent tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Verifying allocated space
The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Growing APFS Physical Store disk1s2 from 832,982,462,464 to 2,000,189,177,856 bytes
Modifying partition map
Growing APFS data structures
APFS Container Resize error code is 49180
A problem occurred; undoing all changes
Modifying partition map
Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures
-bash-3.2#
```

Comment: Rule 1: before doing anything that might possibly lose your data, make sure you have a good backup of everything you don't want to lose. Preferably two backups. (BTW, rule 2 is that *anything* you do on your computer might possibly lose your data; repartitioning is just more dangerous than most other things. Rule 3 is that leaving your computer idle might lose your data too.)

Comment: The usual command to fix this type of problem is `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0`.

Comment: ```diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0``` returned APFS Container Resize error code 49180. A quick search indicated that rebuilding my fusion drive might solve it. Is that where I should go or are there any other potential paths I could take? I'd really prefer not having to wipe my drive.

Comment: Based on the output you posted, you could try `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 2000188149760`.

Comment: Same error, again through recovery mode's terminal.